# How to save two entries in one table row in Magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, model, sql, table

I have to save In and Out timing of customer and their In and Out location, I want to save all the data in one row.

I am getting status `1/0 1==` In DATA, `0==` Out DATA, but how to save it in the same row?

Here are both my In and Out functions:

```
public function ws_pushPunchInData($custid,$intime,$inlocation,$device_id,$status,$create_at)

{
    //Mage::log("intime: ".$intime.", outTime: ".$outtime.", create_at: ".$create_at, null, 'punchinout.log', true);
    $res = $data = array();
    $res['code'] = 400;
    $res['msg'] = "Invalid request";
    if ($custid)
    {
        $current = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        try
        {
            $data = array(
            'manager_id' => strval($custid),
            'punch_in_time' =>$intime,
            'in_coordinates' =>strval($inlocation),
            'device_id' => strval($device_id),
            'status' => strval($status),
            'create_at' => $current;     

            $smodel = Mage::getModel("manager/asmtracker")->setData($data)->save();

            $res['code'] = 200;
            $res['msg'] = 'Successfully updated';

        }catch(exception $exception)
        {
            $res['msg'] = 'Unable to process';
        }  
    }
    return $res;
}
 public function ws_pushPunchOutData($custid,$outtime,$outlocation,$device_id,$status,$updated_at)

{
    //Mage::log("intime: ".$intime.", outTime: ".$outtime.", create_at: ".$create_at, null, 'punchinout.log', true);
    $res = $data = array();
    $res['code'] = 400;
    $res['msg'] = "Invalid request";
    if ($custid)
    {
        $current = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        try
        {
            $data = array(
            'manager_id' => strval($custid),
            'punch_out_time' =>$outtime,
            'out_coordinates' =>$outlocation,
            'device_id' => strval($device_id),
            'status' => strval($status),
            'updated_at' => $current);     

            $smodel = Mage::getModel("manager/asmtracker")->setData($data)->save();

            $res['code'] = 200;
            $res['msg'] = 'Successfully updated';

        }catch(exception $exception)
        {
            $res['msg'] = 'Unable to process';
        }  
    }
    return $res;
}
```

Comment: create one array save in out data with key and convert it into json and save it

Comment: You mean in single record  against each entry ? Your code is saving data twice for in and out ?

Answer (score 3):

Save those data in array and convert that array to json and you can save that Json in database

```
<?php 
    $jason_data =  json_encode($array);
?>
```

after that Save that `$jason_data` in database

**Edit**  part after @Arunendra  suggestion

```
 public function ws_pushPunchOutData($custid,$outtime,$outlocation,$device_id,$status,$updated_at)

{
    //Mage::log("intime: ".$intime.", outTime: ".$outtime.", create_at: ".$create_at, null, 'punchinout.log', true);
    $res = $data = array();
    $res['code'] = 400;
    $res['msg'] = "Invalid request";
    if ($custid)
    {
        $current = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        try
        {

           $smodel =  Mage::getModel("manager/asmtracker")->load($custid,'manager_id');
            $data = array(
            //'manager_id' => strval($custid),
            'punch_out_time' =>$outtime,
            'out_coordinates' =>$outlocation,
            'device_id' => strval($device_id),
            'status' => strval($status),
            'updated_at' => $current);     
             $smodel->setData($data);  
             $smodel->setId($smodel->getId());
             $smodel->save();     
            //$smodel = Mage::getModel("manager/asmtracker")->setData($data)->save();

            $res['code'] = 200;
            $res['msg'] = 'Successfully updated';

        }catch(exception $exception)
        {
            $res['msg'] = 'Unable to process';
        }  
    }
    return $res;
}
```

Comment: yeah again same timing (y)

Comment: Yeah, Do you have same solution or different one ??? @GopalPatel

Comment: Exactly same solution. I gave solution in comment and you gave it into answer on same time

Comment: She asked for same row not column. I believe she want to update the record

Comment: @GopalPatel May be fraction seconds would be differ

Comment: @Arunendra may be you right let me update

Answer (score 2):

i think you want to update the second time here is logic

```
public function ws_pushPunchOutData($custid,$outtime,$outlocation,$device_id,$status,$updated_at)

    {
        //Mage::log("intime: ".$intime.", outTime: ".$outtime.", create_at: ".$create_at, null, 'punchinout.log', true);
        $res = $data = array();
        $res['code'] = 400;
        $res['msg'] = "Invalid request";
        if ($custid)
        {
            $current = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            try
            {
                $data = array(
                'manager_id' => strval($custid),
                'punch_out_time' =>$outtime,
                'out_coordinates' =>$outlocation,
                'device_id' => strval($device_id),
                'status' => strval($status),
                'updated_at' => $current);     
    $smodelitem = Mage::getModel("manager/asmtracker")->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('manager_id',$custid)->addFieldToFilter('device_id',$device_id)->getFristItem();
     if($smodelitem):
                $smodel = Mage::getModel("manager/asmtracker")->setId($smodelitem->getId())->setData($data)->save();
    endif;
                $res['code'] = 200;
                $res['msg'] = 'Successfully updated';

            }catch(exception $exception)
            {
                $res['msg'] = 'Unable to process';
            }  
        }
        return $res;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You will need unique record id when you store your first IN record. Udated code below

   ```
   public function ws_pushPunchInData($custid,$intime,$inlocation,$device_id,$status,$create_at)

   {
     //Mage::log("intime: ".$intime.", outTime: ".$outtime.", create_at: ".$create_at, null, 'punchinout.log', true);
     $res = $data = array();
     $res['code'] = 400;
     $res['msg'] = "Invalid request";
     if ($custid)
     {
         $current = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        try
       {
       $data = array(
       'manager_id' => strval($custid),
       'punch_in_time' =>$intime,
       'in_coordinates' =>strval($inlocation),
       'device_id' => strval($device_id),
       'status' => strval($status),
       'create_at' => $current;  

        //updated code
       $manager_model = Mage::getModel("manager/asmtracker");
       $manager_model->setData($data)->save();
       $last_inserted_id = manager_model->getId(); 

       $res['code'] = 200;
       //send this IN record unique auto generated id in response
       $res['In_Record_Id'] = $last_inserted_id;
       $res['msg'] = 'Successfully updated';

   }catch(exception $exception)
   {
       $res['msg'] = 'Unable to process';
       }  
       }
       return $res;
    }
   ```

Store "In_Record_Id" in your app from above response. When OUT request sent then pass this "In_Record_Id" id from your app to your server and you can get that id in your code using GET or POST. check below updated code

```
 //added one parameter here in function
public function ws_pushPunchOutData($custid,$outtime,$outlocation,$device_id,$status,$updated_at,$last_in_id)

    {
       //Mage::log("intime: ".$intime.", outTime: ".$outtime.", create_at: ".$create_at, null, 'punchinout.log', true);
$res = $data = array();
$res['code'] = 400;
$res['msg'] = "Invalid request";
if ($custid)
{
    $current = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    try
    {
        $data = array(
        'manager_id' => strval($custid),
        'punch_out_time' =>$outtime,
        'out_coordinates' =>$outlocation,
        'device_id' => strval($device_id),
        'status' => strval($status),
        'updated_at' => $current);     
        //assuming in your table unique key column name is Id

        //updated code
        $manager_model = Mage::getModel("manager/asmtracker")->setId($last_in_id);
        $smodel = $manager_model->setData($data)->save();

        $res['code'] = 200;
        $res['msg'] = 'Successfully updated';

    }catch(exception $exception)
    {
        $res['msg'] = 'Unable to process';
    }  
}
return $res;
   }
```